# How I Can Open URL Directly With App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

- I have a google spreadsheet
- I get the link to Publish that Spreadsheet as Web Page, PDF, Microsoft Excel, CSV and others from "Publish to the Web"  menu.
- There is the sample link :

  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ14uGARmUSk6dx40XwkrbP7oD90M8h-Sn1EZNr0sNBKkA0PmQsY5WC6MXLA4ltVrrDB4lEjbP63ABt/pub?gid=1602250439&single=true&output=pdf
- I want to make Clickable images in my spreadsheet, with App Script as trigger.[image: Direct Link to Download Spreadsheet]

[image: Set Clicable Image]

How to make trigger Clickable Image  with App Script ?
I Use this script but didn't work.

```
    function downloadPdf() {UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ14uGARmUSk6dx40XwkrbP7oD90M8h-Sn1EZNr0sNBKkA0PmQsY5WC6MXLA4ltVrrDB4lEjbP63ABt/pub?gid=1602250439&single=true&output=pdf')};
```

How I must write the script?
So the link can direct open, and the file can be download directly with that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up a url in another tab

```
function openUrl(){
  let html = '<h1>Dummy Dialog</h1><script>window.onload = function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(url){window.open(url,"_blank");google.script.host.close();}).getMyUrl();}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Dummy Dialog");
}

function getMyUrl() {
  console.log('getting url');
  return "http://www.google.com";
}
```